# Concatenate columns with specific width integers

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame 'df' with two integer columns:

```
C1 C2
8  49
.. ..
```

From this, I want to create a new column that concatenates both columns with a specific width. C1 should be two digits wide and C2 three digits wide, so that the resulting column looks like this:

```
CODESUM 
08049
```

The first 0 is of less importance to me.

So far I've tried using the `str()` function with `str(df.C1)`, without success. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use double [`str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
df['new'] = df.C1.astype(str).str.zfill(2) + df.astype(str).C2.str.zfill(3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works as a charm! Is there any possibility to also save the result as a new column in the same dataframe? I can't recall this new column when df.head()  :(

Comment: There is no new column called `new` ?

Comment: Nope :( maybe I have to set something when opening it? I used: pd.read_csv('file.csv')

Comment: @Unicoln - It is correct way for create `DataFrame`. If test `print (df.columns)` after my code, what return?

Comment: I get all column titles, but still no 'new'

Comment: Alternative solution is `df.assign(new=df.C1.astype(str).str.zfill(2) + df.astype(str).C2.str.zfill(3))`, how it working?

Comment: That shows me the whole table with the new column at the end, but when I execute 'df.head()' there's no new column again. I think it maybe something related to saving the new dataframe. I'm using Atom with Hydrogen and this should have some relation with this

Comment: I never meet with this problem, unfortunately. If use `df = df.read_csv('yourfile')` then `df['new'] = df.C1.astype(str).str.zfill(2) + df.astype(str).C2.str.zfill(3)` and last `df.to_csv('another_file.csv')` there is no new column in file?

Answer (score 0):

you could simply try the following:

```
df['CODESUM'] = df['C1'].astype(str).str.zfill(1) + df['C2'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

"+" works for str concatenation

Comment: Thanks David! Also fast :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension and formatted strings (Python 3.6+):

```
df['new'] = [f'{i:02d}{j:03d}' for i, j in df[['C1', 'C2']].values]

print(df)

   C1  C2    new
0   8  49  08049
```

F-strings often improve performance:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*100000)

%timeit [f'{i:02d}{j:03d}' for i, j in df[['C1', 'C2']].values]               # 458ms / loop
%timeit [str(i).zfill(2)+str(j).zfill(3) for i, j in df[['C1', 'C2']].values] # 1.03s / loop
%timeit df.C1.astype(str).str.zfill(2) + df.astype(str).C2.str.zfill(3)       # 1.02s / loop
```